# Converting a nested collection using Dozer

Tags: java, dozer

I have a class A which has a nested set of class B:

```
public class A {
    private Set<B> children;
}

public class B {
    private int value;
}
```

I also have a class C which has a nested set of class D:

```
public class C {
    private Set<D> children;
}

public class D {
    private int value;
}
```

Now given a List of A, how do I convert it to a List of C? Ideally I should not have to supply any mapping hints since I am using generics. For example:

```
List<A> src = new ArrayList<A>();
// ----- Add some A's to src -----
List<C> dst = mapper.map(src, List<C>.class);
```

Obviously, the syntax of last line is not correct. What should it be? Also how do I tell Dozer what type of a List or a Set to create?

Thanks.

Naresh

Comment: @MatthewSmith See my answer below

Answer (score 4):

This is actually answered in their FAQ, but it's all the way down in the advanced section for some reason.  I don't think this is an advanced topic, I think it's a common thing to want to do.  [You do it with a collection hint.](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/faq.html#collection-hints)

> ## When mapping collections, how do I tell Dozer what type of data objects I want in the destination collection?
>
> Hints are supported to
> handle this use case. Hints are not required if you are using JDK 1.5
> Generics because the types can be auto detected by Dozer. But if you
> are not using generics, to convert a Collection/Array to a
> Collection/Array with different type objects you can specify a Hint to
> let Dozer know what type of objects you want created in the
> destination list. If a Hint is not specified for the destination
> field, then the destination Collection will be populated with objects
> that are the same type as the elements in the src Collection.
>
> ```
> <field>
>   <a>someList</a>
>   <b>otherList</b> 
>   <b-hint>org.dozer.vo.TheFirstSubClassPrime</b-hint> 
> </field>
> ```

That answer shows you how to do it in xml.  Here's how you can do it in java code with a Mapping:

```
import org.dozer.loader.api.BeanMappingBuilder;

import static org.dozer.loader.api.FieldsMappingOptions.hintB;

public class Mapping extends BeanMappingBuilder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        mapping(Subject.class, JsonSubject.class)
                .fields("names", "names", hintB(JsonName.class));
    }
}
```

The hint tells dozer, "this list of A's should be converted to a list JsonName instances".  Here's how you add this mapping to your mapper:

```
    mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
    mapper.addMapping(new Mapping());
```

Comment: Worked exactly as intended.  I am using this in dropwizard to convert my domain POJOs to representations and have nested representations.  You have be careful with your lazy + eager loading still, but dozer carries everything you need over and will use your nested representations with this hinting.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply expand this list convertion. Dozer convert JavaBeans and such objects, not collections. So, if you want to pass collections, you can create a wrapper like

```
public class EntityConverter {
    private Mapper mapper;

    public EntityConverter(Mapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    public <F, T> List<T> convert(List<F> fromList, final Class<T> toClass) {
        return Lists.transform(fromList, new Function<F, T>() {
            @Override
            public T apply(F from) {
                return convert(from, toClass);
            }
        });
    }

    public <F, T> T convert(F from, final Class<T> toClass) {
        if (from == null) return null;
        return mapper.map(from, toClass);
    }
}
```

Note: This code use Guava.